# AsyncTask and Database operations in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I finished reading the Cursors and AsyncTasks chapter in Head First Android Development, and I'm still not sure when to use AsyncTask and when not to when performing database operations.

Suppose I'm at an activity which, when it ends, writes to sqlite database and sends the user back to the main activity (using `finish()`), which displays a list of data that is fetched from the database.
The list of data obviously has to update instantly, just as the user enters back to MainActivity. Does this mean I shouldn't use AsyncTask in this situation? What other choices do I have here? I don't want to let the user see the changed list of data after MainActivity is already visible.

A simpler scenario: The user clicks a button that should display database information in a TextView. Should this be done in a separate thread? I'm not sure, because the TextView must be updated immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice for read & write data in the database is: **do it in a separate thread**. Because it can take a lot of time, if the amount of data is fairly large or the query itself is too complicated, do it in the main thread can cause ANR.

If you want to display data changes immediately, you can do it as following:

1. place a method in the ui activity to change ui according to the parameters
2. triggered update ui through invoke the method above in the async callback

as for your last example, u can update the content of the textview immediately in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask class

if you are not using AsyncTask u can just update ui in other thread through one of the ways below:

1. Activity$runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable)
2. new Handler(Looper.MainLooper()).post(Runnable runnable) //create handler for main thread, and post runnable to execute in main thread
3. send message to message queue,  then handle the message and update ui in the main thread's handler

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should do database queries on a separate thread, but if you're sure the database is relatively small(light) you could perform it on the main thread. but its always best practice to do potential long running tasks on a different thread.